# Adding div to a generated div using XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I have created a JQuery script which ran via the html page to which I now need to make it run from an XML.

In the beginning the page when the script was running the page looked something like this.

```
<div id="main-container">
<div id="container" class="container " style="width: 1906px; height: 953px; margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible;">
<div class="inner" style="background-color: transparent; width: 1906px; height: 953px;">
<div class="second-container overflow-hidden" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px;">
<div class="layer" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px; visibility: hidden; display: block; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: auto;">
<img class="bg" src="../img/bg.png" style="padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 1906px; height: 953px; margin-left: -953px; margin-top: -476.5px; visibility: visible;">
```

whereby the classes `inner` and `second-container` are automatically created by the jQuery i.e. in the html itself you would have...

```
<div id="main-container">

    <div id="container" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">

        <div class="layer" style="delay: 1100; animation: all;">

            <img class="bg" src="../img/bg.png" >
```

So what I have done is the following:

XML:

```
    <root
    template.root.style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; margin: 0 auto;">

    <item
        template.item.style="delay: 1100; animation: all;">
        background="images/bg.png"
        imageone="images/test.png"
        imageoneclass="img1-b1"
        template.image1.style="position: absolute; top: 10; left: 300px; direction: left; delay: 10;" />
</root>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var player = jQuery;

    player.noConflict();

    player(document).ready(function () {

        var body = documnet.getElementsByTagName("body");

        player.ajax({
            type="GET",
            async: "false",
            url: "data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {

            var container = player('<div id="main-container"></div>).appendTo(body);

            player(xml).find('root').each(function () {

                var root = player('<div id="container"></div>.appendTo(container);
                root.attr('style', player(this).attr('template.root.style'));

                var layer = "player('<div id="layer"></div>.appendTo(root);
                layer.attr('style', player(this).attr('template.item.style'));

            });
```

My issue is how do I get the `div` class `layer` to be inside the automatically generated `div` `inner` using this principle?

Once more apologies if there are any typos or missing any missing " or ' since at the moment it is working it is just a case of finding out if what I am asking can be done.

Comment: you are creating elements with id `container` and `layer` in a loop, it will create multiple elements with those ids which is invalid - use class attribute instead of ID in such scenarios

Comment: Whilst I'm not sure how you're doing this it seems as though your are not adding the `<div class="inner" ...`, the `<div class="second-container ...` in any way via javascript or XML?

Comment: Inner and second-container are generated via another jquery script which I created, to which I am now trying to use what it generates to be parsed using XML